# Database fields dont update when click event is triggered

Tags: sql, vb.net

the code I have runs without any errors but the database doesnt update its fields.

This runs with no errors but database doesnt update its fields

```
Sub UpdatePassword(ci As ClientInformation)
    Try
        Using con As New SqlCeConnection(GetConString)
            If con.State = Data.ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
            Dim adapt As New SqlCeDataAdapter(String.Format("UPDATE AdminInformation 
            where ClientID='{0}' SET PWD='{1}'", ci.ClientID, ci.Password), con)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

my ClientInformation Class:

```
Public Class ClientInformation
    Public Property ClientID As String

    Public Property SubscriptionEndDate As Date

    Property FirstName As String

    Property Surname As String

    Property Email As String

    Property Company As String

    Property PostalAdd As String

    Property Country As String

    Property Tel As String

    Property Fax As String

    Property Password As String

End Class
```

my event handler:

```
Protected Sub btnChangePass_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    btnChangePass.Click

    Dim ci As New ClientInformation

    If txtBoxNewPass.Text = txtBoxConfirmNewPass.Text Then
        ci.Password = txtBoxNewPass.Text
        lblConfirmPasswordMsg.Visible = False

        dh.UpdatePassword(ci)

        lblPasswordChanged.Visible = True
        txtBoxNewPass.Text = ""
        txtBoxConfirmNewPass.Text = ""
    Else
        txtBoxNewPass.Text = ""
        txtBoxConfirmNewPass.Text = ""
        lblConfirmPasswordMsg.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

my connection string:

```
Private Function GetConString() As String
    Return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conStringLicenses").ConnectionString
End Function
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

PS database is sql compact, visual studio 2012, windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query should be like this

```
UPDATE AdminInformation SET PWD='{1}' where ClientID='{0}'
```

You started your ***WHERE*** clause before your ***SET***

***UPDATE:***

Try changing

```
Dim adapt As New SqlCeDataAdapter(String.Format("UPDATE AdminInformation  where ClientID='{0}' SET PWD='{1}'", ci.ClientID, ci.Password), con)
```

into this

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCeCommand(String.Format("UPDATE AdminInformation SET PWD='{1}' where ClientID='{0}'", ci.ClientID, ci.Password), con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Hi the solution you provided is still not updating the database, the code runs through and the label stating password has changed appears as well, but the field in the database is not showing the update.

Comment: Does anybody have any idea of where I'm going wrong, everything seems to run as expected but the database is not showing the changes, I'm still pretty new to programming so forgive me if there is something I'm missing. Thanks

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested and still the same, the database is showing the same old data for column 'PWD' and is not updating to the new changes.

Comment: Have you tried prompting your query and executing it directly to your SQL Compact? Try doing like
`MsgBox(String.Format("UPDATE AdminInformation SET PWD='{1}' where ClientID='{0}'", ci.ClientID, ci.Password))`

If that one works, then your connection might be the problem

Comment: With the Updated changes you suggested when debugging line by line, there is a sqlceexception caught with message   'There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 25,Token in error = where ]'

Comment: What was the generated query look?

Also, please add (temporarily if you don't mind) a message box inside your Catch part to see if there is an error thrown. Add something like `MsgBox(ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)`

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it, the updated solution worked, the problem was that the current session was not been checked on click for the ClientID so the CurrentID was blank. Thanks for all the help!